# play framework session not found

Tags: java, session, playframework

I'm currently new to Stack Overflow. I've been studying Play framework and now i got stuck in session. I get this error druing compiling my code:

---

```
[info] Compiling 11 Scala sources and 13 Java sources to /home/patrick/workspace/helloworld/helloworld/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /home/patrick/workspace/helloworld/helloworld/app/controllers/Base.java:26:1: cannot find symbol
[error]   symbol:   method session(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
[error]   location: class controllers.Base
[error]         session("connected", "user@gmail.com");
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) javac returned non-zero exit code
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Oct 9, 2018 5:57:49 PM
```

Here is my base class

```
package controllers;

import forms.*;
import models.*;
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.http.*;
import play.Logger;
import play.data.*;
import play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecutionContext;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import javax.inject.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Base extends Action.Simple{   

    @Inject FormFactory formFactory;

    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) {
        Logger.info("Calling action for {}", ctx);
        // String user = session("connected");
        session("connected", "user@gmail.com");
        // Session("key", "example value");

        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }

}
```

Can somebody help me where the error is?